# Import react-table into ClojureScript with Shadow-CLJS

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop, shadow-cljs

Web development newbie here. I'm trying to use the NPM react-table package with a ClojureScript/Reagent project. I'm failing to import the package properly. What I've done:

1/installed react-table through NPM, it's in my project directory

2/in my main namespace, I've included `(:require ["react-table" :as rt])`

In the REPL I can see it's making some connection as just typing `rt` will return `#js {:ReactTableDefaults #js {:data #js [], ...`

How can I actually create a table? I've tried things such as

`rt/ReactTable {:data [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 6 :b 8}] :columns [{:Header "a" :accessor "a"} {:Header "b" :accessor "b"}]}` but I keep hitting into `TypeError: module$node_modules$react_table$lib$index.ReactTable is not a function`

I've also read https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2017/11/10/js-dependencies-in-practice.html but that didn't help me enough.

**Update** - using figwheel I'm getting somewhere, and this is what I'd like to reproduce in shadow-cljs:

In project.clj: `[cljsjs/react-table "6.8.6-0"]`

In the "view" namespace: `(:require [cljsjs.react-table] [reagent.core :as r])`

Then this actually displays a table:

```
(def ReactTable (r/adapt-react-class (aget js/ReactTable "default")))
(defn test-table []
  [:div {:style {:width 320}}
  [ReactTable {:data    [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 6} {:a 6 :b 8}]
               :columns [
                     {:Header "a" :accessor "a" :width 200}
                     {:Header "b" :accessor "b" :width 100}]
           :showPagination false
           :defaultPageSize 3}]])

(defn main-panel []
  [test-table])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a full code example of what you actually tried? Kinda hard to tell whats going on with a tiny snippet without context. It looks like you are on the right track and just might be passing props incorrectly (eg. CLJS data instead of JS objects/arrays)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`react-table` uses a "default" export which you likely didn't use in the `shadow-cljs` build but sort of did in the cljsjs variant (ie. `(aget js/ReactTable "default")`).

So the correct way to do this is:

```clj
(ns your.app
  (:require ["react-table" :as rt :default ReactTable]))

(defn test-table []
  [:div {:style {:width 320}}
    [:> ReactTable {:data ... :columns ...}]])
```

The translation table in the [docs](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_using_npm_packages) might be a useful reference.

Comment: Thomas perfectly answered my question - I've since built an example template https://github.com/alex314159/react-table-vega-template